# Sorting a queue based on this criteria

Tags: c++

I have a queue that stores pointers to Node objects which are defined as:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node(int, char, Node*);
    void setC(char);
    char getC();
private:
    int x;
    char c;
    Node* next;
};
```

Here, `c` can be either 'S', 'M' or 'L'. (small, medium or large). Now, I want to sort this queue in the ascending order of sizes like all 'S' nodes at the beginning/front, followed by all the 'M' nodes and all the 'L' nodes at the end.

Efficiency is not really a criteria. How do I go about it?

Comment: that is not a queue then, a queue is not sorted since its first in first out.

Comment: You can empty and reload it in sorted order.

Comment: @jgr208 there are priority queue which are kinda sorted. being c the "priority" that fits better what Corey wants

Comment: that makes no sense really, why dont you just make an array and sort the array. you are doing twice the work.

Comment: @Diego yes that is true forgot about those!

Comment: If no one is asking you to reinvent the wheel, use an already developed list with a sort function. Standard, Boost, your call.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/):

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node { /* ... */ };

// 'S' < 'M' < 'L'
bool operator< (const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs)
{
    switch(lhs.c) {
        case 'S': return !('S' == rhs.getC());
        case 'M': return ('L' == rhs.getC());
        case 'L': return false;
        default:  throw "must be S, M or L";
    }
}

int main() {
    priority_queue<Node> pq;

    pq.push(Node('S'));
    pq.push(Node('M'));
    pq.push(Node('L'));
    pq.push(Node('S'));
    pq.push(Node('M'));
    pq.push(Node('L'));

    while(pq.size()) {
        cout << pq.top().getC() << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }
}
```

will give them in descending order:

```
L
L
M
M
S
S
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create three stacks and then empty the queue and placing each type in one of the stacks. Then just fill the queue again start with stack 'S' and then stack 'M' and last 'L'.

This is not efficient and maybe storing whole queue in an array and then sort it and replace in queue is a better way.